# INVALID_ENCRYPTED_ID when trying to get invoice details

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Using the /v1/invoicing/invoices/invoice_id API in the PayPal Sandbox to retrieve invoice information, I am getting the following error no matter which invoice I use:

```
{
"name": "INVALID_ENCRYPTED_ID",
"message": "Invalid encrypted id",
"information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/#errors",
"debug_id": "c64c84ba18ede",
"details": [{
        "error_code": "27"
    }
]
```

}

I have tried other APIs such as creating an invoice, sending an invoice, etc and they all work fine with the same credentials.

I can't find any mention of this error anywhere on PayPal or using Google.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was using the invoice number, not the invoice ID.